# Rearranging a biclustered matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I currently have a $77\times 38$ matrix, and I have used a clustering algorithm to cluster the row data and column data. The rows and columns of my matrix correspond to a list of country codes (not in numerical order). That is, I have a list of numbers:

```
{10, 28, 34, 44, ...}
```

where country 10 corresponds to row 1, country 28 to row 2, etc. I have a corresponding list for the columns of my matrix. I have independently clustered the columns and rows into groups of 3. For example, the row clusters look like so:

```
{{10, 1, 4, 2, ...,37 }, {28, 34, 27, 21, ..., 18}, {38, 20, ..., 12}}
```

Again, I have another clustering for the columns. I want to rearrange the rows and columns of my matrix such that the clustered rows and columns are next to one another. Using my example row cluster list, I want to rearrange the matrix such that row 1 corresponds to country 10, row 2 to country 1, row 3 to country 4, etc. After this, I wish to do the same with the columns of my matrix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include a small example matrix that demonstrates the idea... it's hard to follow the logic when you explain it in 3 paragraphs.

Comment: With incomplete data and no working code you are literally making your (possibly simple) question sound like an excruciating puzzle Dr. Watson..:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** I think [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) covers all the manipulations you need to do on the rows and columns of your matrix:

```
mtrx = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 3}];
Grid[Thread[{{HoldForm[mtrx], HoldForm[mtrx[[{2, 1, 4, 3}, All]]],
HoldForm[mtrx[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]], HoldForm[mtrx[[{2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]]],
HoldForm[mtrx[[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 2}]]]},
TableForm /@ {mtrx, mtrx[[{2, 1, 4, 3}, All]],
   mtrx[[All, {2, 1, 3}]], mtrx[[{2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]],
    mtrx[[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 2}]]}}],
 Spacings -> {1, 1}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

If `data` is your data matrix and `rowClusterList` and `columnClusterList` are the partitions corresponding to the row and column clusterings, you can re-arrange the rows and columns of your data matrix using:

```
 data[[Flatten@rowClusterList,Flatten@columnClusterList]]
```

---

**Original post** based on guessing the details of the problem --( keeping for now hoping it may prove relevant and useful based on expected updates by the OP to his post.)

A small example for illustration

```
(* a short list of countries *)
(* countryList=RandomChoice[CountryData[#, "Name"] & /@ CountryData["Countries"], {10}] *)
countryList = {"Cyprus", "Macau", "Barbados", "Kuwait", "Hungary", 
   "El Salvador", "Jamaica", "Oman", "Myanmar", "Peru"};
ticks = Thread[{Range[10], countryList}];
(* example data *)
data = RandomInteger[{5}, {10, 10}];
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {countryList, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countryList}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> All, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks,  None}, {ticks /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 90 Degree], None}}, 
ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
 (* example clustering of the rows and columns:*)
 rowClusters = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, 9, 4}, {7, 8, 10, 6}};
 columnClusters = {{10, 2, 3, 9}, {1, 6, 8, 5}, {7, 4}};
```

Reshuffle the data matrix and the row/column indices to match the new row and column orderings:

```
 newdata = data[[Flatten@rowClusters, Flatten@columnClusters]];
 xticks = Thread[{Range[Length[data]], countryList[[Flatten@rowClusters]]}];
 yticks = Thread[{Range[Length[Transpose@data]], 
       countryList[[Flatten@columnClusters]]}];
 TableForm[newdata, TableHeadings ->  {countryList[[Flatten@rowClusters]], 
    Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countryList[[Flatten@columnClusters]]}]
```

[image]

```
 ArrayPlot[newdata, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Mesh -> {Join[{0},  Accumulate@(Length /@ rowClusters), {Length[data]}], 
     Join[{0}, Accumulate@(Length /@ columnClusters), {Length[data]}]}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Directive[GrayLevel[.1], Thickness[.01]], 
        Directive[GrayLevel[.1], Thickness[.01]]}, 
   Frame -> True,  FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], 
   FrameTicks -> {{xticks, None}, {yticks /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 90 Degree], None}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {60, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I feel one more step is necessary: The cluster lists are list of numeric labels, they are not row or column numbers. So, you have to make an additional translation to arrive at that.

Comment: @Sjoerd, good point. Will post an update with the needed step.